# HDMI to LVDS - screen gets power but no image

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have an old laptop screen which I took out of its enclosure. After getting a HDMI to LVDS board I'm trying to hook it up. The power source seems to be correct. The screen actually gets power but it seems no image is provided. When I hook the HDMI cable to my laptop it also doesn't recognise it as an external screen.

Things which I've tested:

- Laptop to external screen works
- HDMI cable works
- HDMI to LVDS probably works, I have 2 and tested them both
- Cables probably work, have all new cables

Any tips?

[HDMI to LVDS controller board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRAFP.jpg)

[Screen gets power](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLFmG.jpg)

Comment: LVDS is a low-level interface, and not an interface to which you can connect any panel.  A LVDS interface has to be configured for a specific panel.  The configuration is usually hardwired or in ROM, so the LVDS board specs should mention which panel(s) it can w  So are these LVDS boards that you have intended for that specific laptop screen?  BTW what you call *"screen gets power"* seems to be just the backlight turning on; that is electrically separate from the LCD panel that generates the actual image.

Comment: Ok thank you! It seems you are right and that the company I've ordered them from did not preprogram the correct settings. If thats fixed it should be solved. Thanks!!!